# unable to run django in pycharm 3.4 after update?

Tags: django, pycharm

I had this project working on pycharm 3.3 I guess. After my holidays, when I got back to work, pyCharm prompted with the latest update. I updated pyCharm and now I cannot run my previous Django projects which used to work fine. Here is the stacktrace on pycharm Console

```
bash -cl "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py runserver /Users/sridhar/Documents/python_workspace/django_formsets"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 170, in run_module
    mod_name, loader, code, fname = _get_module_details(mod_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 103, in _get_module_details
    raise ImportError("No module named %s" % mod_name)
ImportError: No module named manage

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: just try to import the project and configure run/debug configuration

Answer (score 2):

In **File >> Settings >>**

1. >> **Project Interpreter:** Check your interpreter is correct and have django package
2. >> **Django :** Check your project root, settings, and manage script path is correct.

Comment: I checked that interpreter is fine. I am  also able to run the program successfully from commandline using manage.py runserver.

Comment: I am not talking about global python settings or paths. Did u check them in IDE as i said? because some reason pycharm may loose project settings after updates.

Comment: yes, I did from pycharm IDE and obviously that will the first thing to check.

Comment: I get this error now when I restarted pycharm that just to make sure change of interpreter has effect: No manage.py file specified in Settings->Django Support
/Users/sridhar/Documents/virtualenvs/django_1.3/django_1.3/bin/python /Users/sridhar/Documents/virtualenvs/django_1.3/django_1.3/bin/django-admin.py runserver 8077
Error: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.

Comment: For some reason IDE cannot read DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE settings in its settings file. May u delete .idea folder  in your project while ide is closed and restart the ide and set the project as django project again?

Comment: **<envs>
<env name="PYTHONUNBUFFERED" value="1"/>
<env name="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="settings"/>** This line must be problematic in workspace.xml

Comment: so what do you want me to try out now? delete .idea folder?

Comment: i wrote. **delete .idea folder in your project folder**

Comment: I deleted. I still get same error as above in the comment

Comment: Can u post <envs> <env name="PYTHONUNBUFFERED" value="1"/> <env name="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="settings"/> and related parameters in your workspace.xml and the file path of your settings module related to your project path?

Comment: I no longer have workspace.xml. It got deleted with .idea folder correct?

Comment: yes. And now u must check and set 2 settings in my answer.